When exactly do volume 2 figurines start to appear?
The great internet says it's after defeating the second boss. But I am pretty certain that that didn't unlock the second volume of figurines for me (I never saw a single one through the whole third world), and I am very certain that it didn't unlock the machine in Waddle Dee Town.
So what is the exact requirement for finding green capsules in the wild, and what exactly unlocks the machine?

What sites are you using? https://wikirby.com/wiki/Figure#Volume_series says that Vol. 2 is after "Wondaria Remains".

@Malady https://www.ign.com/wikis/kirby-and-the-forgotten-land/All_Figures and https://gameranx.com/features/id/328270/article/kirby-and-the-forgotten-land-how-to-get-all-gacha-figures/ and https://www.thegamer.com/kirby-and-the-forgotten-land-figures-all-guide-locations/ and plenty of others say after Tropical Terrror. Given that that's patently false, I don't know what to trust.

I bet that Gameranx and TheGamer are just copying from IGN?
